# Pergunta simples sobre Laravel e a função get()

Tags: laravel

Ola, estou utilizando laravel ja a algum tempo e estou familiarizado com o framework, porem gostaria de saber a real necessidade de utilizar o metodo get() ao chamar uma classe. Por exemplo:

Utilizando get():

```
$pessoa = \App\Pessoas::where('ID_CD_TIPOPESSOA',3)->where('IN_STATUS',1)->get();
```

sem get():

```
$pessoa= \App\Pessoas::where('ID_CD_TIPOPESSOA',3)->where('IN_STATUS',1);
```

Qual seria a diferença entre usar o get() e não usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você utiliza o `get`, ele executa a `query` que está armazenada na instância do `Builder` e ele retorna os valores dessa consulta.

Quando você não utiliza o `get`, você apenas retorna uma instância do `Builder` e com isso, você pode armazenar numa variável e/ou manipular da forma que achar necessário.

Além do `get`, há outras funções também que executam a `query` e te retornam algum valor como a função `find` ou `first`.

De um modo geral, use o primeiro se não há regra de negócio ao realizar uma consulta, basta empilhar os `where` e no final adicionar o `get`. 
Caso contrário, armazene a instância do `Builder` em uma variável e faça as devidas verificações.

Segue de exemplo um código para o segundo caso:

```
// Prepara uma query de base
$query = \App\Pessoas::where('ID_CD_TIPOPESSOA', 3)->where('IN_STATUS',1);

// Caso tenha um status que precise ser adicionado dinâmicamente
if($request->has('status_amais')
    $query->where('IN_STATUS', $request->input('status_amais'));

// Depois realiza a consulta
$results = $query->get();
```